# OpenRDF TurtleParser not handling prefixes properly

Tags: rdf, sesame

Wordnet 3.0 ( http://semanticweb.cs.vu.nl/lod/wn30/ ) is in Turtle format, and I am having trouble getting org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser to parse the Manifest.ttl file ( https://gist.github.com/1181802 ).

It looks like the parser isn't dealing with prefixes properly -- evidently it thinks they're null:

```
org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: org.openrdf.rio.RDFParseException: 
Not a valid (absolute) URI: nullwn30 [line 15]
```

I have never ventured into to the RDF-loading space before so it's very likely I'm missing something.

Any ideas on where to look?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error in that Turtle file. Specifically, this snippet:

```
:wn30
    a lib:Namespace ;
    lib:mnemonic "wn30" ;
    lib:namespace wn30: .
```

The identifier `:wn30` is a qualified name using the default namespace (default, because it has no prefix, in constract to e.g. `lib:mnemonic`). However, the Turtle document does not contain a namespace declaration for the default namespace.

By the way, which version of Sesame are you using? I tested this briefly on the most recent release and it still gave me an error, but that error was a bit more helpful in hunting down the problem: "Default namespace used but not defined [line 14]".

To fix this, the document should include a namespace declaration for the default namespace, e.g:

```
@prefix : <http://example.org/> .
```

Comment: Thanks Jeen. I'm using 2.5.0 -- isn't that the latest?

Comment: It is, yes. The difference must be in the way the parser is invoked then: if you were using the parser programmatically (rather than via the Workbench), I suppose you simply haven't set up a ParseErrorListener (which would give you the more detailed error msg).